# how to find user is logged in different browser or different system at a time using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am implementing Online Examination System. If user is logged in different browsers at a time it should not be logged in. As well as Different system. Please help me how to restrict the user logging in different browsers. Please give any Example Code. So that i can understand easily. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You need to store the ipaddress, browser information and etc in database or filesystem and use

Comment: Do not store login information in a session, store it in your central database

Comment: Could you explain clearly...how to validate the cookie and storing

Comment: If you given any example code i can understand easily..

Answer (score 3):

Try the following logic:

You can keep the username of logged in users in a list. Then each time a new login is made, check if the user is in that list. If it is, then redirect him to the error page else let hime proceed with examination. On logout you will remove the user from the list.

Comment: You'll need some way of handling timeouts too, I'd suggest also logging the time whenever an action is taken from the original login then checking if any old logins were in the last X hours/minutes

Comment: +1 Simple, yet efficient. Could even use a text file to maintain that list instead of a DB.

Comment: how to do with cookies and sessions..?

Comment: [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) and [cookies](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php)

Comment: If you given any example code i can easily understand better. when i am searching regarding this i find information not code.So please explain

Comment: Stack overflow is not for teaching you how to read documentation, it's for helping with specific problems.